# ios app returning hijri calender year in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have an iOS app and it was working fine upto iOS 7.

I was generating list car model years from 1970 to current year. Heres the code

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger currentYear = [components year];
DLog(@"current year = %ld", (long)currentYear)

for (NSInteger yearStart = (currentYear + 1); yearStart >= kHJVehicleStartingModelYear ; yearStart--) {
    [self.carModels addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)yearStart]];
}
```

The problem is that when run in iOS 8. Depending on the locale settings it returns the current year of Hijri calendar. e.g. it is returning 1435 instead of 2014. And the loop does not execute to generate list of models.

How to get gregorian current year in iOS 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create an instance of [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/initWithCalendarIdentifier:) with the `NSGregorianCalendar` type:

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: I think upto ios version 7 by default [NSCalendar currentCalendar] would return the NSGregorianCalendar. But as of iOS 8, it depends on the locale settings.

Comment: No the `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` will return the selected calendar in the locale settings on iOS 7 and lower as well.